# Redemption error reading creationdate and receivedate

Tags: outlook-redemption

I am using Redemption 5.0.2 and I get this error when I attempt to read the RDOMail CreationTime and ReceiveTime in Quick view:

> {"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."}

and this error when the code executes the line:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'System Error.  Code: 18.
>   There are no more files'

We are attempting to migrate to Windows 10 and Office 365 any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the older versions of Redemption and a Windows update missing some timezone resource files. You need to use the latest version of Redemption.